# When doing a search I want to skip all code that ends in a closing tag

Tags: html, regex

I have HTML that looks like this:

```
 <td class="danish"> Det
         tycker jag!</td>
```

I'm fixing the line break with this:

```
<td class="danish">(.*)
\s*(.*)</td>
```

But sometimes the HTML ends in a tag on the same line:

```
 <td class="danish">Det tyckeg jag</td>
```

I want it to skip lines like these when searching and find the next broken line.

In case anyone thinks it's just a frivolous thing to make the code look good, the rest of the code looks like this (not required reading):

```
<td class="danish"> Det
  tycker jag!</td>
<td>      
  <?php audioButton("../../audio//det_lyder_godt","det_lyder_godt"); ?>
```

I ultimately have to take the text in the table and replace the one in the audiobutton a thousand times, but that's a different problem

Comment: What's about using Notepad++ combined with HTML Tidy for HTML5 (experimental)?

Comment: I don't see the problem.  Your regex matches the broken line and doesn't match the unbroken one.  What am I missing?

Comment: Hi Alan. This regex <td class="danish">(.*) finds everything until the end of the line, including the closing tag. I want it to skip everything that has the closing tag and find the next broken line. I'm only interested in fixing lines with a break in them.

Comment: "so many times but it is not getting to me..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
(<td class="danish">(?:(?!</td>).)*)\r?\n\s*
```

This matches from `<td class="danish">` to the next newline, *unless* there's a `</td>` tag first.  Replace with `"$1 "` or `"\1 "` (without the quotes).

Using `\r?\n` instead of a literal newline makes the regex more robust.  Even better is `\R`, if your regex flavor supports it.

Comment: This is it! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

`\s` means "any white-space character", which includes spaces and new lines. You could explicitly search for lines that **must** contain a new line, by using something like:

```
<td class="danish">(.*)\n\s*(.*)</td>
```

Note the additional `\n` in the regex.

Comment: Hi Tom. The white-space is not the issue. This regex <td class="danish">(.*) finds everything until the end of the line, including the closing tag. I want it to skip everything that has the closing tag and find the next broken line. I'm only interested in fixing lines with a break in them. So, it will look something like <td class="danish">(.*)(regex that will read the </td> and make it disregard this line)